# JAXB or Xstream on a Jersey Restful application

Tags: jaxb, jersey, xstream

I want to know which solution is better for a Jersey Rest Web service. In some cases JAXB is not able to handle some types. Is it better to use XStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your use case - if you think JAXB will be significant limitation, you can use XStream. Btw Jersey recently added support for MOXy, which could help you overcome some corner cases in JAXB Reference impl in JDK.

Pro JAXB

- out of the box functionality with Jersey
- ability to specify own JAXBContext
- stable; lots of tests / support from Jersey/JAXB team

Con JAXB

- it doesn't work as expected for some corner cases (java/xml binding has limitations due to different nature of these languages)

Pro XStream:

- you probably have some experience with that

Con XStream:

- you'll need implement support for it (MessageBodyReaders/Writers) in Jersey

Comment: +1 for MOXy.  The announcement that Jersey added support for MOXy means that they now exercise MOXy in test suites.  Since MOXy is a standard JAXB provider you can also use it in previous releases of GlassFish.  For an example of using MOXy with GlassFish 3.0.1 see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

Answer (score 8):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> I want to know which solution is better for a Jersey Rest Web service.

**JAXB (JSR-222)** is the default binding layer for JAX-RS.  This means that if you have the following method, JAXB will automatically be used to convert the return type (`Customer`) to XML (and JSON when using Jersey).

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("{id}")
public Customer read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Customer.class, id);
}
```

If you need more control over your JAXBContext you can use a JAX-RS mechanism called `ContextResolver`:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html

> In some cases JAXB is not able to handle some types

JAXB is able to handle all types, either by default or through the use of an `XmlAdapter`.  Below are some examples where an `XmlAdapter` is used with the Joda-Time types and some immutable domain objects:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

> Is it better to use XStream?

Below is a link to a blog entry I wrote where I mapped the same object model to the same XML document using both JAXB and XStream you may be interested in:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

JAXB implementations such as MOXy also contain many extensions you will find useful such as XPath based mapping (`@XmlPath`) and an external mapping document:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

For an example of using MOXy as the JAXB provider in Jersey see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explainations and reference links. I'll try MOXy and hope it will be the right tool.

Comment: @Lahniep - If you need any help with MOXy you can reach me through my blog:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html